# "self.included?" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In the following code,

```
module Test
  @connection = nil
  def self.included?(base)
    @connection = base
  end

  def print
    puts @connection
  end
end

class ModuleTest
  include Test
end

m = ModuleTest.new
m.print
```

why is `@connection` nil when printing?

Comment: Do you really want `@connection = base`, or did you mean `@connection == base`? It seems very odd to have a method ending in a question mark that assigns a value and always returns it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `print`, it prints the instance variable `@connection` of an instance of `ModuleTest`. You have two other places in your code referring to `@connection`, but those point to the instance variable `@connection` of the instance `ModuleTest` of the `Class` class, and are a different thing.

Furthermore, even the latter `@connection` (the one for `ModuleTest` class) does not get its value `base` until you do `included?`.

The instance variable for the instance of `ModuleTest` created is thus initialized to `nil` by default when called by `puts` within `print`.

Answer (score 4):

Almost right, with a couple of tweaks it works:

```
module Test
  def self.included(base)
    @@connection = base
  end

  def print
    puts @@connection
  end
end

class ModuleTest
  include Test
end

ModuleTest.new.print
```

Issues:

1. the callback is *included* without a *?*.
2. in class methods, it makes more sense to use class variables than instance variables

Comment: I've always read that class variables are frowned upon due to the potentially unpredictable behavior. I prefer to use instance variables on the class and then self.class.instance_variable_get(:@my_var) if I need to get that variable in an instance. It's a little more code, but much more predictable.

Comment: @Beerlington - I have read that too, but only as opinions, w/o any solid example. Can you link to a blogpost / question that explains the unpredictable behavior? On hindsight, classes are also objects in Ruby, so ideally, we shouldn't have much issue.

Comment: @Swanand - just do a google search for Ruby class variables and you'll find tons of examples. Here's one that focuses on inheritance: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/ Also, the book Eloquent Ruby has some examples if you're interested in it.

Comment: *"Unpredictable?"* Well, class variables are inherited and the subclass shares the variable with the superclass. Often that's exactly what you want and always predictable. If you really want something private to a superclass or something then you will need to use a class instance variable, sure.

Comment: @Beerlington Instead of groping inside your class's instance variables you should probably be making a class-level accessor, either `def self.foo; @foo; end` or `class << self; attr_reader :foo; end`.

Comment: @Phrogz great suggestion. I'll probably start doing that since instance_variable_get never really felt right.

Comment: @Beerlington Actually, in Ruby, class variables are *not* static. And the hate in general is aimed at *static* variables IMO. So in Ruby class variables can be *very* nifty. `ActiveResource`, `Rack` use them liberally.